# Sniff tcp connection and forward to TCP connection on other adapter

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, tcp

I have a system with two network adapters. One of the network adapters is connected to a port mirror, so it sees all the traffic in the network. I'd like to sniff that connection for a certain TCP connection with a specific port number, and forward all the data of that connection that to TCP server using the second network adapter.

What I have tried so far:

- Use `socat` to listen on a port and fork it to another port. This works when a TCP connection would be directly made with the port `socat` is listening on, but I don't know how this could be replaced with the input from a sniffed connection.
- `tcpdump` to sniff all the data. However, I'm unsure how to forward this data to a different TCP connection.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell us what your underlying goal is? I'm worried this might be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). I have a suspicion your real goal would be well-handled by a reverse proxy, load balancer, or NAT.

Comment: The data that is sniffed needs to be logged, for which I use Wireshark. I do not have any influence on the network that is being sniffed. Furthermore, to allow for real-time analysis of that data, the data has to be forwarded/relayed to one or more other machines on a different location. I currently use a Java application on Windows that sniffs the data and puts it on a different TCP connection like described in the question, but I wondered if it would also be possible using Linux.

Comment: Have you tried using netcat for this?

Comment: I'm familiar with netcat and I use it sometimes to create a TCP server or client. However, I'm not sure how I would be able to use netcat for the problem I described.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is port forwarding.

You could try something like this.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to x.x.x.x:2222
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d x.x.x.x --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
```

The above example will forward all traffic received ingress on eth0 on port 1111 to IPv4 address x.x.x.x on port 2222.